# Fastlane, can an AppleScript be ran as a step in a lane?

Tags: fastlane

I’m trying to perform some some steps within my fastlane from an AppleScript. I’ve not been able to find any documentation about this.

I know you can run shell scripts from the fastlane but I’m not sure whether you can run AppleScripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to create a shell script that executes the AppleScript:

`<root>/test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

osascript <<EOD
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
    end tell
EOD
```

`<root>/fastlane/Fastfile`:

```
platform :ios do
    lane :test do
        sh('../test.sh')
    end
end
```

and run it using `bundle exec fastlane test`

Comment: Thanks, would I just be able to tag parameters on the end of the shell script sh call?

Comment: @Jules, Sure, just change it to `sh('../test.sh', 'param1', 'param2')`. Let me know if it works as you need it to.

Comment: thanks, any ideas who I would use that in the applescript. I'm just trying to piece together an approach to recording video / audio in quick time, from an automated test.

Comment: In this example, simply replace the first line of the script with `tell application "$1"` and call the script using `sh('../test.sh', 'Google Chrome')`.

Comment: Thanks so much :)

Comment: Glad I could help you :D